# JQuery Cycle2 First Slide Flashes Wrong Position

Tags: jquery, plugins, slideshow, center

For some reason when I first open the page for my slideshow, the first image momentarily appears on the side of the div before the Cycle2 Centered Slides plugin moves it to the center.

To get an idea of what I'm talking about, look at the Cycle2 Center plugin page itself:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/center.php

If you put your screen over the slideshow at the bottom, you can actually see the image jump from the top-left (in Chrome..) to the center when refreshing. My images are bigger than that so you will see an image on the side of the container for 1-2 seconds before moving to the center.

Anyone know of a fix? I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Can you provvide an example (js/html/css) ?